module not found error with poetry and multistage docker image
I am trying to execute a multistage docker build to create a light image. I am using poetry for dependency management. My dockerfile is as below
FROM python:3.12-slim as builder

RUN pip install poetry
RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN python -m venv .venv
RUN poetry install

FROM python:3.12-slim as base
COPY --from=builder /app /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH="/app/.venv/bin:$PATH"
CMD ["python", "-m", "main"]

My main.py file is (yes i know I am not using the yaml import, just trying to test dependency resolution)
import yaml
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   print(f'Hi, Poetry')

My pyproject.toml file is as below
[tool.poetry]
name = "poetrydemo"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
readme = "README.md"
package-mode = false

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
pyyaml = "^6.0.1"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

After i build
docker build -t poetrydemo:latest .
and run
docker run poetrydemo:latest 
I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml' error
Examining the contents of the container,
docker run -it --entrypoint sh poetrydemo:latest
I see the .venv file is copied over correctly and the path is set correctly, but still does not find the module. What am I missing? If it helps my folder structure is as below


Your setup here is mixing a couple of different tools.  You're both manually creating a virtual environment and also asking Poetry to install one.  poetry install creates its own virtual environment, though, and installs packages there.  You're copying the manually-created virtual environment, but not the Poetry environment, from one stage to the other.
A multi-stage build isn't benefiting you here at all.  It's useful if you need some tool to build your application but not to run it.  In the context of a Python package, it's useful if you have a C extension that needs a C toolchain to build it (if you have a RUN apt-get install build-essential line).  Your Dockerfile doesn't have anything like that.
For the simple setup you show here, I'd remove the multi-stage build and the manual virtual environment.  There are a couple of options for Python package management (including installing packages directly into the "system" Python, but isolated in this image) but maybe the most straightforward for this setup is just to embrace Poetry
FROM python:3.12-slim as builder

RUN pip install poetry
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./
RUN poetry install
ENTRYPOINT ["poetry", "run"]
CMD ["python", "-m", "main"]

(The Poetry FAQ has a couple more hints on building efficient Dockerfiles that I won't reproduce here.)

There are a few things I am aware of and I understand I can optimize for example. I put together a trivial use case for the sake of the question and did not want to post my entire project.
I could have used poetry's ability to create a virtual env here, but I took a different approach, I do not think that impacts the issue i am having (let me know if it does)
As poetry installs it's packages into the virtual env it finds instead of creating a new one.
I also am using a multi stage build as I would like to avoid copying poetry and other dev /test dependencies I have in my real project.

In the original question, what makes Poetry aware of the ./.venv virtual environment?  You might need to say something like RUN . ./.venv/bin/activate && poetry install, for example.
